# How to replicate Postman POST API request using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can currently use Postman to retrieve an "access_token" but I'm trying to replicate this in ajax (for the purpose of playing around with a few things in jsfiddle)

So in Postman, I have:

- A POST request URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/token
- No active headers
- Body, consisting of 4 key-values (see below)

[image]

If I run that I get a response containing my access_token:

[image]

I'm trying to replicate this in ajax and after some help on here I was able to create the following script:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/token',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: '***',
    client_secret: '***',
    resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
  }),
  success: data => {
    console.log(data.access_token)
  },
  error: (xhr, textStatus, error) => {
    console.log('rr', error)
  }
});
```

This returns an error each time in the console:

[image]

I feel like I'm close but can not figure it out

Comment: `"rr"` isn't a particularly useful error message.  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, what is the actual response from the server?

Comment: One request seems to be x-www-form-urlencoded (as defined by the API) and the other is JSON. So the Content-Type of the request would be wrong/ not compatible.

Comment: I get a CORS error.  After a little more digging,  it appears that the server (Power BI) will not permit access from a Browser.   Annoying as I just wanted to use a private jsfiddle to play around with some functionality

Answer (score 0):

Your POST is `x-www-form-urlencoded` but your ajax data is a `json` string.

When data is passed as a string it should already be encoded using the correct encoding for `contentType`, which by default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

> When data is an object, jQuery generates the data string from the
> object's key/value pairs unless the processData option is set to
> false. For example, { a: "bc", d: "e,f" } is converted to the string
> "a=bc&d=e%2Cf". If the value is an array, jQuery serializes multiple
> values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
> (described below). For example, { a: [1,2] } becomes the string
> "a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2" with the default traditional: false setting.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

So try removing the `JSON.stringify` and just passing the POJO. e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/token',
  data: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: '***',
    client_secret: '***',
    resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
  },
  success: data => {
    console.log(data.access_token)
  },
  error: (xhr, textStatus, error) => {
    console.log('rr', error)
  }
});
```